# Angular 7 not downloading the file properly

Tags: angular, typescript, download, httpclient, http-get

I'm new to Angular. I started using Angular 7. I'm trying to download a excel file in angular. Here is my service code.

event.service.ts

```
getReport(reporturl: string) {
        return this.http.get(reporturl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .pipe(
                // tap(data => console.log('getEvent: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

In my component file,

event.ts

```
handleExcelDownload(data) {
    this.eventService.getReport(`${data}/true`)
      .subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.showFile(response, "Grid.xlsx");
          // let mediaType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';
          // let blob = new Blob([response], { type: mediaType });
          // let filename = 'Grid.xlsx';
          // saveAs(blob, filename);
        },
        (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }

  private showFile(blob: any, filename: string) {
    // It is necessary to create a new blob object with mime-type 
    // explicitly set otherwise only Chrome works like it should
    let newBlob = new Blob([blob], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });

    // IE doesn't allow using a blob object directly as link href 
    // instead it is necessary to use msSaveOrOpenBlob
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
      return;
    }

    // For other browsers: 
    // Create a link pointing to the ObjectURL containing the blob.
    let data = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = data;
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      // For Firefox it is necessary to delay revoking the ObjectURL
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(data);
    }, 100);
  }
```

The downloaded excel is always corrupt. But in my console log, I'm getting array buffer. The Excel download is working fine when I tested in server. Please assist on where I'm wrong.

** Request**

[image: Second Request]

Request has 200 success and when i preview the request, it has the array buffer.

**Preview of response.**

[image: Array buffer]

But if i open this server url manually at this point file is downloaded and that is not corrupted. Please assist on where I'm going wrong? I tried many articles in internet none seems to work.

Comment: The OPTIONS request is CORS related, not Angular
https://spring.io/understanding/CORS

Comment: This means? Is that making trouble with excel download?

Comment: Not at all. It seems your CORS are working correctly, you may remove it from your question.

Comment: Can you please help on why the Excel file is corrupt on download? It's working fine when I tested in the server

Comment: Can you try changing response type `responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob`

Comment: @VenuDuggireddy `ResponseContentType.Blob` is not available in angular 7. Please assist

Comment: Try `responseType: 'blob'`

Comment: I tried and checked console -  I get a Blob object with size 9500 and type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` but excel is corrupt on opening

Comment: Figured out the issue. Excel is working fine. I checked the excel in another device. Its working fine. The problem is with the Excel app installed in my machine.